# window.location is not working when using bootstrap form validation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using bootstrap form validation and then submitting my form to php using ajax. Everything is working well, however once the ajax is returns I want to redirect my browser to index.php but it is not working, it is simply refreshing the page, although my database is getting updated normally.

I think that it could be something related to the js function of the form validation but I am not sure.

Below is the js code:

```
var completed = false;

// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
  "use strict";
  window.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function () {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener(
          "submit",
          function (event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
              completed = true;
            }
            form.classList.add("was-validated");
          },
          false
        );
      });
    },
    false
  );
})();

//This file is used to authenticate the password upon registtration

$(document).on("submit", function () {
  if (completed == true) {
    var inputName = $("#inputName").val();
    var inputEmail = $("#inputEmail").val();
    var r_password = $("#r_password").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var province = $("#province").val();
    var city = $("#city").val();
    alert("hello1");
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/user_reg_config.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        new_user: 1,
        inputEmail: inputEmail,
        inputName: inputName,
        r_password: r_password,
        country: country,
        province: province,
        city: city,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        alert("hello2"); //This alert is displayed with nor problems at all
        window.location = "index.php"; //THIS IS NOT WORKING
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You're not preventing the default form submission in the case the validation passes, the form is submitted and the pending submission prevents location to change.

Comment: How do I fix that @Teemu?

Comment: ?? Just prevent the default action of submission in any case.

Comment: @Teemu lol How did I miss that????? Thank you so much